# Parsing of nested structures and object model

Tags: java, c++, oop, parsing

I am trying to parse a binary file format with nested structures. In procedural pseudo-code, the process would be as such:

```
// A structure contains:
// tag | oneof(a, b, c) | oneof(oneof(aa, ab, ac), oneof(ba, bb, bc), oneof(ca, cb, cc))
PROCEDURE parse() {
    RECORD read_type;

    read_tag(read_type);

    if (read_type == TYPE_A) {
        read_a(read_type);
        if (read_type == TYPE_AA) {
            read_aa();
        } else if (read_type == TYPE_AB) {
            read_ab();
        } else if (read_type == TYPE_AC) {
            read_ac();
        }
    } else if (read_type == TYPE_B) {
        // see above
    } else if (read_type == TYPE_C) {
        // see above
    }
}
```

An outer structure such as AA can not be interpreted without context from its parent object A, which in turn requires its tag/header to interpret. When working with these structures, it makes sense to manipulate structures that contain A, that contain AA, etc., but never only the A or AA portion of a structure.

My question is then how to create a class model for this procedure. Should the structure be:

```
class Base;
class A: Base;
class B: Base;
class C: Base;
class AA: A;
class AB: A;
class AC: A;
// ...
```

In which case, AA might be constructed as such:

```
AA::AA(): A() {
    read_aa();
}

A::A(): Base() {
    read_a();
}

Base::Base() {
    read_tag();
}
```

However, the issue would be that it would not be possible to know what derived object to construct without first constructing the base object. This could be worked around by having a constructor AA::AA(A*) that copy constructs its parent, but this seems like an unnecessary inefficiency. Further, this would require an external factory function such as:

```
Base *read_object() {
    Base *base = new Base();
    if (b->tag_type == TYPE_A) {
        A *a = new A(base);
        if (a->tag_type == TYPE_AA) {
            return new AA(a);
        } else if (a->tag_type == TYPE_AB) {
            // ...
        } else if (a->tag_type == TYPE_AC) {
            // ...
        }
    } else if (b->tag_type == TYPE_B) {
        // ...
    } else if (b->tag_type == TYPE_C) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The other option is to have classes that refer to sub-regions of the structure such as:

```
class CompleteStructure;
class StructureA;
class StructureB;
class StructureC;
class StructureAA;
class StructureAB;
class StructureAC;
// ...

class CompleteStructure {
    union {StructureA a, StructureB b, StructureC c} sub;
}

class StructureA {
    CompleteStructure *parent;
    union {StructureAA aa, StructureAB ab, StructureAC ac} sub;
}

class StructureAA {
    StructureA *parent;
}
```

In this case, the constructor CompleteStructure::CompleteStructure() would read the tag and then construct one of StructureA, StructureB, or StructureC, which would in turn construct is own sub-structure. The issue with this is that each sub-structure would need an explicit reference to its parent in order to "cast" up the hierarchy and implement its methods/functions.

Is one of these approaches better than the other in terms of space/time efficiency and "cleanness"? Is there a superior third approach?

EDIT:
To respond to the two answers below, the question is both about parsing and object behavior. My initial goal is merely to read the structures from the file, print out their fields, and then write them back to disk in the same order. Later on, there will be additional goals such as finding all instances of A-derived structures and sorting them by certain fields or checking for illegal combinations of structures (e.g. having both BA and BB).

EDIT2:
Here is an example schema of one of the structures I refer to (with generic field names). u8/16/32 refer to integer types, sz is a C string, upper-case names are fields that need to be read, and constants are prefixed with underscores.

```
DEF AA {
    // Identifies and deliminates complete records.
    TAG {
        u32 SYNC_CODE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }

    // Metadata for high level identification of data.
    A {
        u32 TYPE = __TYPE_A;
        u16 CATEGORY = __CATEGORY_1; // A defines the "category" of the following file data
        u32 NUM_OF_KV_PAIRS;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_KV_PAIRS; ++i) { // unspecified metadata
            sz KEY;
            sz VALUE;
        }
        u8 HAS_EXTENSION_FLAG = true; // indicates presence of next record
        if (!HAS_EXTENSION_FLAG) {
            DEFAULT_PARAMS; // legacy
        }
    }

    // Indicates a specific data layout and version.
    AA {
        u32 TYPE = __TYPE_AA;
        u8[16] ACCESS_KEY;
        u32 NUM_OFFSETS;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OFFSETS; ++i) {
            // stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get _"The issue with this is that each sub-structure would need an explicit reference to its parent in order to "cast" up the hierarchy"_ Can you elaborate a little bit more? Why do a sub-structure let's say AA needs to know anything about its super-structure A for example?

Comment: Fields in AA refer to initialization structures in previous structures to define their semantics. Moreover, for type safety, one might want to refer to a complete structure by its specific type, such as a function `process(AA a) { do_something(a.complete_structure()); }`.

Comment: _HAS_EXTENSION_FLAG = true; // indicates presence of next record_ Is this about the existence or not of the AA structure or does it mean something else?

Comment: Yes. AA/AB/AC are extensions that supercede the old A record. This mechanism is used throughout to "version" structures.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer if some approach is better in terms of effeciency without a more concrete problem description. Below you can find some food for thought.

**Point 1:** When thinking about class design it worths to also examine the desired behaviour and not just the data. The fact that the binary format used for storage, may or may not imply a hierarchy, should be taken into account of course, but it should not be the primary concern.

As an example, assume we have a `Person` class that has a `height` field and a `Rectangle` class that also has a `height` field. They both share some data but having only this information makes them rather irrelevant to each other. If we define the context and we say we want to draw them on the screen then suddenly the `height` field has a more specific meaning. Now inheriting a `Drawable` perhaps makes more sense.

The question in your case is how we will use them? What common operations can we do if we have a list of `{A, B}` or `{AA, BB}` or even `{A, BB}`? Can we somehow manage them together? This is an important point that you should take into account.

**Point 2:** You say that *"it makes sense to manipulate structures that contain A, that contain AA, etc, but never only the A or AA portion of a structure"*. So I understand that `AA` *is-a* `A`, but that the opposite is also true. If this is the case, then it makes sense to have `Base, A, B, C` as abstract classes and only be able to instatiate directly the last level `AA, BB` etc.

**Point 3**: On the other hand it might be better to use composition over inheritance if the different structures just define some data and not some behaviour. E.g. will we invoke a method on them like `process()` that would operate on the data? Or do we want to use the structures themselves as data?

```
class X {
    Base base;
    A a;
    AA aa;
    process() {
        // this is different than calling base.process() + a.process() + aa.process()
        // do we need one over the other? both?
        process(base) + process(a) + process(aa);
    }
}
```

**Point 4:** Regarding the order of instantiation while reading, this should not be a problem.  Perhaps you could read the information as you go storing it temporarily and only instantiate a class after you know its full type (i.e. you reach the last level).

I hope that helps

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify point 1. Regarding point 4, wouldn't this require an extra copy/read of the data?

Comment: @user2363399 It would need an extra copy yes (for all instances not per instance). Another read I don't think so. I was thinking a case like: `A value1 = readValue(); A value2 = readValue(); ... and finally ` new AA(value1, value2, ...);` For the next instance values can be reused. I don't know how large are your structures though and if this is possible. I was just providing ideas

Comment: These will be bulk structures that can range from a few bytes to several kB/MB (or possibly even GB, but those I will implement as a handle, since they contain raw arrays). Generally, I would like to keep the data contiguous to avoid indirections, but perhaps that is misguided?

Comment: @user2363399 to be honest it is hard to tell without a specific example. If it is possible perhaps you could add to your question one of those structures with the fields and their sizes so we can get an idea

Comment: I put in an example structure schematic in the question. The main point is that each section of the structure contains an identifier and indicates the presence of a following substructure. Additionally, the size of each structure is defined by its field.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't clearly explain what you think you are doing, or what the actual problem is (ie. what you should be doing).

You need to very clearly define which of A, AA, AB are **entities** with their own distinct existence -- and where are the **child relationships** which you're supposedly parsing. You say nested structure but don't detail it.

As another answer mentioned -- OO is about **behaviour**, not about **data modelling**.

Leaning heavily on inheritance, especially since you don't know what you're constructing, sound like it would be a complete mistake. Inheritance heirarchies in general are only useful when you need behavior (methods that calculate or do things) & can efficiently divide that behavior-space by some class heirarchy and benefit from that.

Your problem as stated above, is just a parsing problem. You could as well use a Stack and some internal state (say a StringBuilder, at the most trivial) to read & build up parsing-state while using the Stack to push & pop nesting levels.

In fact, the above is a great way to implement most kinds of parsers.

A more-sophisticated alternative (also common in parsers) is to build an AST. These are very efficient & light-weight to build & traverse.

```
class AstNode {
    protected AstNode down;     // first child.
    protected AstNode across;   // next sibling.

    public void addChild (AstNode child) {
        if (getDown() == null) {
            // First Child;
            this.down = child;
            return;
        }
       // Sibling to existing Children.
       AstNode last = down;
       while (last.getAcross() != null)
           last = last.getAcross();
       last.across = child;
       // done.
    }
}
```

With an AST, you can also put properties/ members on for NodeType, Data, Type (lexical) etc and effectively build a powerful data-structure in its own right.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you're right that parsing is a big part of this. I think AST would be overkill since this is a binary format without the complicated rules of precedence or such in e.g. programming languages. I think a tree of some kind might be the right fit though. Each portion of the structure can be a node in the tree, although that doesn't really leverage the language type system as I would have liked.

Comment: AST doesn't embody precedence rules or have any overhead to support them, it's just a light & reliable way of storing output (with or without precedence). A stack-based parsing & parser rules are what actually apply syntax rules & precedence.

Comment: Leverage the type system? If you put a Data member in your AST, or (sometimes) Data and Type members, you can attach structured objects once the parse has progressed a bit further -- and use the language's type-system on those. Works well.